# \def allowing multiple formats

Tags: macros, definition

For example, I want to define this

```
\def\normal(#1,#2){\mathcal N\left( #1, #2 \right)}
```

which makes it convenient to write a normal distribution (e.g., \normal(0,1) gives N(0,1)).

However, I have been using the following definition in so many articles

```
\newcommand{\normal}[2]{\mathcal N\left( #1, #2 \right)}
```

by which \normal{0}{1} gives N(0,1).

So I want to define a command \normal which first sees whether its argument starts with "(" and defines the command accordingly.

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with LaTeX's `\@ifnextchar` to detect an opening parenthesis and act accordingly

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\normal{\@ifnextchar(\normalB\normalA}
\newcommand\normalA[2]{\mathcal N\left(#1,#2\right)}
\def\normalB(#1,#2){\normalA{#1}{#2}}
\makeatother
```