# scanf functionality in TeX?

Tags: pdftex, formatting, input, foreach, pgffor

Is there a function akin to scanf of C that can simultaneously parse stdin or txt and assign them to variables? For example, I am trying to typeset a pdf from a text file. The first line contains the number of lines I should typeset, and the rest contains three numbers that form an addition problem.

```sh
$ cat input.txt
5
5 2 7
4 7 11
8 0 8
7 5 12
9 7 16
```

In C one could do as follows:

```c
$ cat program.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    FILE* input = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    int n, a, b, c, i;
    fscanf(input, "%d", &n);
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        fscanf(input, "%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);
        printf("%d + %d = %d\n", a, b, c);
    }
    return 0;
}
$ gcc program.c -o program.o
$ program.o
5 + 2 = 7
4 + 7 = 11
8 + 0 = 8
7 + 5 = 12
9 + 7 = 16
```

I am close to a working example and just need to find the right command.

```
$ cat program.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\newread\input
\openin\input=input.txt
% Read first line and assign to n
\foreach \i in {1,...,n} {%
    % Read line and assign to a, b, c
    $\a + \b = \c$\\%
}%
\closein\input
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Don't use `\input` as your macro name! That's an important macro of LaTeX (and a primitive in TeX)!

Comment: There are packages that might come in handy, see `csvsimple`, `datatools`, and probably others.

Comment: also `pgfparser`, see https://tikz.dev/module-parser

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ while possible, I'd argue that `pgfparser` isn't the right tool to get something `fscanf`-like out of the box, it'd require coding much of the parsing...

Comment: The feature used in the answers below is that TeX allows pattern matching for macro arguments, like `\def\xyz#1 #1 #3{output using the arguments}` which could be called as, for example, `\xyz a 35 $x^2$` which assigns a to #1, 35 to #2 and $x^2$ to #3. This is not restricted to patterns with spaces (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/616367/def-allowing-multiple-formats for an example).

Answer (score 8):

[image]

I added a computation to check the answers you had put in the file.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newread\x
\openin\x=input.txt
\begin{document}

\read\x to \varn

\def\do#1 #2 #3 #4\relax{%
\par
$#1 + #2 = #3\quad \mbox{check: } \the\numexpr#1+#2\relax$%
}

\loop
\read\x to\varline
\expandafter\do\varline\relax
\edef\varn{\the\numexpr\varn - 1}
\ifnum\varn>0
\repeat

\end{document}
```

Or as L3

```
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\ior_new:N\l_input
\ior_open:Nn\l_input{input.txt}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\ior_get:NN\l_input\l_n

\cs_new:Npn\l_format:w #1 ~ #2 ~ #3 ~ #4\q_stop{
\par
$#1 + #2 = #3\quad \mbox{check: ~ } \int_eval:n{#1+#2}$
}

\bool_do_until:nn{ \int_compare_p:nNn \l_n = 0 }
{
\ExplSyntaxOff
\ior_get:NN\l_input\l_line
\ExplSyntaxOn
\exp_after:wN\l_format:w\l_line\q_stop
\cs_set:Npx\l_n{\int_eval:n{\l_n - 1}}
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd use `expl3`.

The first line is stored for deciding the number of operations to perform (it must be at most equal to the number of the following lines).

The other lines are mapped, with the help of a locally defined function, for which you specify the format of the arguments and what to do with them.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.txt}
5
5 2 7
4 7 11
8 0 8
7 5 12
9 7 16
4 4 8
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-1.txt}
3
5 2 10
4 7 28
8 0 0
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\operationsfromfile}{mm+m}
 {% #1 = file name, #2 = args, #3 = template
  \qem_opfromfile:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\ior_new:N \g_qem_opfromfile_ior
\tl_new:N \l__qem_opfromfile_number_tl
\int_new:N \l__qem_opfromfile_current_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \qem_opfromfile:nnn
 {
  \cs_set:Npn \__qem_temp:w #2 \q_stop { #3 }
  \int_zero:N \l__qem_opfromfile_current_int
  \ior_open:Nn \g_qem_opfromfile_ior { #1 }
  \ior_str_get:NN \g_qem_opfromfile_ior \l__qem_opfromfile_number_tl
  \ior_str_map_inline:Nn \g_qem_opfromfile_ior
   {
    \int_incr:N \l__qem_opfromfile_current_int
    \int_compare:nF { \l__qem_opfromfile_current_int > \l__qem_opfromfile_number_tl }
     {
      \__qem_temp:w ##1 \q_stop
     }
   }
  \ior_close:N \g_qem_opfromfile_ior
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\operationsfromfile{\jobname.txt}{#1 #2 #3}{$#1+#2=#3$\par}

\operationsfromfile{\jobname-1.txt}{#1 #2 #3}{$#1\cdot#2=#3$\par}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `\input` primitive instead `\read` primitive. It means that your data are scanned in the main input stream.

```
\def\scanf#1 {\par \def\num{#1}\ifnum\num>0 \expandafter\scanfA\fi}
\def\scanfA#1 #2 #3 {$#1+#2=#3$\par
   \edef\num{\the\numexpr\num-1}
   \ifnum\num>0 \expandafter\scanfA\fi
}
\expandafter\scanf\input input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the mood for "oldschoolness", you can implement a loop based on `\immediate\read` and `\ifeof` and decrementing.

But the TeXbook says in Chapter 20: Definitions (also called Macros):

> To get input from an open file, you say
> `\read⟨number⟩to⟨control sequence⟩`
> and the control sequence is defined to be a parameterless macro whose replacement text is the contents of the next line read from the designated file. This line is converted to a token list, using the procedure of Chapter 8, based on the current category codes.
> Additional lines are read, if necessary, until an equal number of left and right braces has been found. **An empty line is implicitly appended to the end of a file that is being `\read`**.

I. e., with existing files opened via `\openin` for reading via `\read` TeX always pretends that there is an additional empty line appended to that file.

Thus, if the file exists, then `\ifeof` can only be true after doing some `\read`, whereby also the appended additional empty line was read.

Therefore I suggest cranking out empty lines; a line being a TeX-comment is the same as emptiness.

With the example, reading lines of data ends if at most as many entries were read and processed as denoted in the 1st line of the data file.
In case the file does not have that many entries, then reading/processing lines of data ends when the end of the data file is reached.

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}{equationdata.txt}
% Amount of entries to process:
5
% Operand1 Operand2 Result Operator
%   Operator: 0=+, 1=-, 2=*, 3=/
12 34 46 0
90 5 18 3

117 38 79 1

23 4 19 2
6 7 42 2

22 5 110 2

85 17 5 3
\end{filecontents*}


% There is an incorrectness: The line "23 4 19 2" should be "23 4 19 1".
% This is on purpose so you can see that the \ifnum-check with the result calculated
% via \numexpr detects the difference.

\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\FirstOfTwo[2]{#1}
\newcommand\SecondOfTwo[2]{#2}
\newcommand\Exchange[2]{#2#1}

\newread\dataread
\newcommand*\dataline{}%
\newcommand*\scanf[3]{%
  % #1 - file
  % #2 - routine for splitting a line of equation-data into its components - assumes a space token is appended at
  %      the end of the line; the loop does append a space token for you.
  % #3 - separator between calls to  routine for splitting a line of equation-data
  \immediate\openin\dataread=#1 %
  \readdatalinesloop{1}{}{}{\SplitOneDelimitedArgAndDefineScratchmacro{\dataline}}{\dataread}%
  \readdatalinesloop{\dataline}{}{#3}{#2}{\dataread}%
  \immediate\closein\dataread
}%
\newcommand\readdatalinesloop[5]{%
  %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  % #1 - amount of entries to read
  % #2 - separator between calls to prepend in this iteration
  % #3 - separator between calls to routine for splitting a line of data into its components
  % #4 - routine for splitting a line of data into its components - assumes a space token is appended at
  %      the end of the line; the loop does append a space token for you.
  % #5 - \read-handle
  %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \ifeof#5\expandafter\FirstOfTwo\else\expandafter\SecondOfTwo\fi{}{%
    \ifnum\numexpr(#1)\relax<1 \expandafter\FirstOfTwo\else\expandafter\SecondOfTwo\fi{}{%
      %--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      % Read the next line of data from the file:
      %--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \begingroup
      \endlinechar=-1 %
      \immediate\read#5 to \dataline
      %--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      % Check if the next line of data from the file is empty:
      %--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \ifcat$\detokenize\expandafter{\dataline}$\expandafter\FirstOfTwo\else\expandafter\SecondOfTwo\fi
      {%
        \endgroup
        \expandafter\readdatalinesloop\expandafter{\the\numexpr(#1)\relax}{#2}%
      }{%
        \expandafter\Exchange\expandafter{\dataline}{\endgroup#2#4} %
        \expandafter\readdatalinesloop\expandafter{\the\numexpr((#1)-1)\relax}{#3}%
      }%
      {#3}{#4}{#5}%
    }%
  }%
}%

\csname @ifdefinable\endcsname\SplitOneDelimitedArgAndDefineScratchmacro{%
  \def\SplitOneDelimitedArgAndDefineScratchmacro#1#2 {%
     % #1 scratch macro to define
     % #2 number in 1st line of file
     \def#1{#2}%
  }%
}%

\csname @ifdefinable\endcsname\SplitFourSpaceDelimitedArgs{%
  \def\SplitFourSpaceDelimitedArgs#1 #2 #3 #4 {%
     % #1 operand ; #2 operand ; #3 result; #4 number denoting operator
     %--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     % Deliver the tokens forming the equation:
     %--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     $#1\ifcase\numexpr(#4)\relax+\or-\or\times\or\div\fi#2=#3$%
     %--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     % Calculate, using eTeX-extensions' \numexpr - you can comment this out if you don't want it:
     %--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     \Exchange({ }\texttt{\string\numexpr}-calculation %
     \ifnum\the\numexpr(#1\ifcase\numexpr(#4)\relax+\or-\or*\or/\fi#2)\relax=\numexpr(#3)\relax
        also yields%
     \else
        yields a different number%
     \fi
     : \the\numexpr(#1\ifcase\numexpr(#4)\relax+\or-\or*\or/\fi#2)\relax)%
     %--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     % End of code for calculating using \numexpr.
     %--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  }%
}%

\begin{document}
\noindent
\scanf{"equationdata.txt"}{\SplitFourSpaceDelimitedArgs}{\\}
\end{document}
```

[image]