# typesetting equations based on external text file gone wrong

Tags: macros, pdftex, expansion, text, format

This example reads `n` lines and prints them out as addition problems.

```
$ cat equations.txt
8
1 2 3
4 5 9
6 7 13
18 7 25
34 66 100
94 21 115
0 31 31
27 18 45
84 51 135
64 9 73
```

```
$ cat equations.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}

\newread\externalinput
\openin\externalinput=equations.txt

\read\externalinput to \n%

\def\printaline#1 #2 #3{%
$#1 + #2 = #3$\\%
}%

\noindent
\foreach \i in {1,...,\n} {%
\read\externalinput to \eachline%
\expandafter\printaline\eachline%
}%
\closein\externalinput
\end{document}
```

```
$ pdflatex equations.tex
1 + 2 = 3
4 + 5 = 9
6 + 7 = 1
3 18 + 7 = 2
5 34 + 66 = 1
00 94 + 21 = 1
15 0 + 31 = 3
1 27 + 18 = 4
5
```

The file does compile but only one digit of `#3` is printed and `\\` is typeset first. I wanted to go further and add a macro that typesets one of +-*/ but this time it didn't compile at all. In the bottom example `#4` is supposed to determine which symbol is typeset.

```
$ cat equationsb.txt
5
12 34 46 0
90 5 18 3
117 38 79 1
23 4 19 2
6 7 42 2
```

```
$ cat equationsb.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}

\newread\externalinput
\openin\externalinput=equationsb.txt

\read\externalinput to \n%

\def\mathsymbol#1 {%
\ifcase#4 +\or -\or \times\or \div\fi%
}%

\def\printaline#1 #2 #3 #4{%
$#1 \expandafter\mathsymbol#4 #2=#3$\\%
}%

\noindent
\foreach \i in {1,...,\n} {%
\read\externalinput to \eachline%
\expandafter\printaline\eachline%
}%
\closein\externalinput
\end{document}
```

```
$ pdflatex equationsb.tex
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \mathsymbol.
<to be read again> 
                   4
l.11 \ifcase#4
               +\or -\or \times\or \div\fi%
```

Is the expansion order wrong? Also how do I prevent multi-digit numbers from being cut out?

Comment: Instead of reinventing the wheel, have a look at the packages mentioned in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/693679/scanf-functionality-in-tex/693713#comment1721589_693679

Comment: the error you show is simply `\def\mathsymbol#1 {%
\ifcase#4 +\or -\or \times\or \div\fi%
}%`  you can not have `#4` in a one argument macro

Comment: With your 1st example the 3rd argument of `\printaline` is not delimited, so after grabbing the 1st and the 2nd argument either the 1st subsequent non-space-token not in braces or the content of the 1st subsequent brace-group is taken for the 3rd argument. As TeX appends `a character denoted by \endlinechar` at the end of a line and in your case will transform that into a space-token, with your 1st example try `\def\printaline#1 #2 #3 {$#1 + #2 = #3$\\}%`, i.e., a space between `#3` and `{` to have `#3` space-delimited as well.

Comment: With your 2nd example change to `\def\mathsymbol#1{\ifcase\numexpr(#1)\relax+\or-\or\times\or\div\fi}%`  and `\def\printaline#1 #2 #3 #4 {$#1\mathsymbol{#4}#2=#3$\\}%`. (Space between `#4` and `{`.) || Be aware that with equationsb.txt the line `23 4 19 2` yields a false statement. (`\ifcase`-branching starts with 0, so the number 2 denotes the 3rd-ifcase-alternative which is `\times` while you need the 2nd-ifcase-alternative, which is `-` and which is denoted by the number 1. As a rule of thumb, beginning with k=0 the number k denotes the k+1-th alternative in `\ifcase`.)

Comment: Also you may consider removing ```\\``` from the definition of `\printaline` and instead inside the `\foreach`-loop's code that is repeated, as a last thing do `\ifnum\numexpr(\i)\relax=\numexpr(\n)\relax\par\else\\\fi`. Otherwise you might get an underfull-hbox-warning because - after printing the last line - via ```\\``` creating another `\hbox` forming a line of the paragraph is initiated but that line is left empty/that `\hbox` is underfull.

Comment: Be aware that in horizontal mode (the mode where TeX breaks paragraphs into lines automatically) ```\\``` can be considered a directive to break the line. Breaking the line in turn implies that the end of the paragraph is not reached yet but that there will be at least one more line belonging to the paragraph. So if ```\\``` is followed by stuff that ends the paragraph, it is assumed that the "one more line belonging to the paragraph" does not contain material and therefore is empty and therefore forms an underfull hbox.